# Leaflet 'quick start' code snippet giving TypeError: Cannot read properties of null when displaying OpenStreetMap in JavaScript application

Tags: javascript, maps, coordinates, openstreetmap, open-source

getting error when using leaflet a javascript library

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')
```

I am building an application and using openstreet maps with the help of leaflet (version 1.9.4) javascript library..
But when I am using the quick start code snippet of leaflet in my code it is giving error.

**The snippet I am using**

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
```

**The error I am getting**

```
Projection.SphericalMercator.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')
    at Object.project (Projection.SphericalMercator.js:24:43)
    at Object.latLngToPoint (CRS.js:28:40)
    at e.project (Map.js:982:27)
    at e._latLngToNewLayerPoint (Map.js:1510:15)
    at e._animateZoom (Marker.js:330:23)
    at e.fire (Events.js:195:9)
    at e._animateZoom (Map.js:1701:8)
    at e.<anonymous> (Map.js:1679:9)
```

When I am opening the Projection.SphericalMercator file from console to check the error this is what I am getting :-

```
import {LatLng} from '../LatLng';
import {Bounds} from '../../geometry/Bounds';
import {Point} from '../../geometry/Point';

/*
 * @namespace Projection
 * @projection L.Projection.SphericalMercator
 *
 * Spherical Mercator projection — the most common projection for online maps,
 * used by almost all free and commercial tile providers. Assumes that Earth is
 * a sphere. Used by the `EPSG:3857` CRS.
 */

var earthRadius = 6378137;

export var SphericalMercator = {

    R: earthRadius,
    MAX_LATITUDE: 85.0511287798,

    project: function (latlng) {
        var d = Math.PI / 180,
            max = this.MAX_LATITUDE,
**line of error ->  lat = Math.max(Math.min(max, latlng.lat), -max),**
            sin = Math.sin(lat * d);

        return new Point(
            this.R * latlng.lng * d,
            this.R * Math.log((1 + sin) / (1 - sin)) / 2);
    },

    unproject: function (point) {
        var d = 180 / Math.PI;

        return new LatLng(
            (2 * Math.atan(Math.exp(point.y / this.R)) - (Math.PI / 2)) * d,
            point.x * d / this.R);
    },

    bounds: (function () {
        var d = earthRadius * Math.PI;
        return new Bounds([-d, -d], [d, d]);
    })()
};
```